# AWS delete user on my CLI, but not on IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-iam

I have a user on the CLI for AWS,

when I do

> > > aws iam get-user

I get:

```
{
"User": {
    "UserName": "mbeta",
    "PasswordLastUsed": "2018-09-27T00:19:08Z",
    "CreateDate": "2018-02-02T02:38:57Z",
    "UserId": "xxx",
    "Path": "/",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::xx:user/mbeta"
}
}
```

The problem is that the user is overriding the credentials to start a server on "localhost" that uses some AWS credentials

> > > cat .aws/credentials

```
[thaServer]
aws_access_key_id = xxxyyy
aws_secret_access_key = zzz/eee
region = ap-southeast-2
```

So when I try to run the server, it uses my CLI user...

I have asked another colleague to run

> > > aws iam get-user

And he gets:

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

So my question is, how to delete just my CLI information or to point to the correct user for my server credentials?

Not delete my user from IAM. Cheers

Comment: you have to create .aws/credentials file with [default] profile. then it will automatically get the default user of yours from the cli. and if you need to use a different user for server then you must configure aws cli with that user's credentials before you start doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my ~/.aws/credentials I have several profiles:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = <REMOVED>
aws_secret_access_key = <REMOVED>
[k8s]
aws_access_key_id = <REMOVED>
aws_secret_access_key = <REMOVED>
[jenkins]
aws_access_key_id = <REMOVED>
aws_secret_access_key = <REMOVED>
```

All the profiles have different IAM roles and I use them for different tasks. By default, all commands obviously uses the **default** profile.

An example of listing S3 buckets with awscli using **k8s** profile would be:

```
aws s3api list-buckets --profile k8s
```

You have not mentioned what kind of server you are trying to run so I can only give you general solutions, pick anyone of them:

- Change the default profile
- Create a separate credential file and specify the file path in your server configuration
- Create a dedicated linux user to run the server